# Kendo MVVM DropDownList does not clear value when selecting option label

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have 2 dropdownlist which initialized using MVVM. One cascade from the other one.

While everything is alright, I found that when I edit the form, and select the dropdownlist to option label (to clear its value, this is valid as it is not a required field), the value is not clear. Therefore after I click save button, the old value is saved.

Both dropdownlist has such behavior. (Select option label did not reset / clear the value of the model bound behind)

How can I bind a null or empty value, or reset the value when I select the option label ?

```html
<select id="ActualNatureCode"
        data-bind="source: DataSource.NatureCategory, value: ViewModel.ActualNature.FailureCategory"
        data-role="dropdownlist"
        data-value-field="Code"
        data-text-field="Description"
        data-option-label="@Resources.Wording.SelectOne"
        data-value-primitive="true"
        data-auto-bind="true"
        ></select>


<select data-bind="source: DataSource.ActualNatureList, value: ViewModel.WorkOrder.ActualNatureCode"
        data-role="dropdownlist"
        data-value-field="Code"
        data-text-field="Description"
        data-option-label="@Resources.Wording.SelectOne"
        data-cascade-from="ActualNatureCode"
        data-value-primitive="true"
        data-auto-bind="false"
        data-select-one="true"
        data-filter="contains"
        ></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm usually not working with KendoUI for ASP.NET, but in Javascript you can set `option-label` to an object with a custom default value, rather than just a text.

```
optionLabel: {
    text: "Select one element...",
    id: null
}
```

You can check the [Dojo](http://dojo.telerik.com/iFibo) I created.

I've checked the API reference, and that option is also available for [ASP.NET](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/aspnet-mvc/Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent/DropDownListBuilder#methods-OptionLabel(System.Object)).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my situation is I have a cascaded dropdownlist, and when I change the parent one to the option label, the cascaded one will change the option label ( and become disabled) as well. It is normal for someone to consider the cascaded dropdownlist has its value set to null, but in fact it is still preserving its old value. Does this solution cater for this situation?

Comment: I've used that configuration a few times even with cascading dropdownlists, and as far as I remember it set value of the cascading dropdownlist correctly. I've been working with angularJS however, so there might be differences which are cause by the framework.

Comment: Thanks...Maybe I can try that out and if it works I will accept your answer :)   But do you know how can I set the value using MVVM style? i.e.  data-xxx-xxx = "optionLabelValue"